# how to call the logPath defined in the main.php of yii?

Tags: php, yii

how to get the logPath defined in the main.php of the config in yii?
I tried ,

```
CFileLogRoute::getLogPath();
```

doesn't work, lol, I don't know how to call it properly to output the value of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you would need that path, but here it goes:

```
foreach(Yii::app()->log->routes as $route) {
    if($route instanceof CFileLogRoute) {
        echo "logPath: ".$route->logPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: aren't there any other way to get that Path , without having to go through a foreach loop ?

Comment: You can configure lots of different log routes. But a `logPath` is only defined for `CFileLogRoute`. So you have to go through all of them to find the right one.

Comment: any other ideas though?

Comment: You have a solution. Not sure what else you want. Anything else would be hacky.

Comment: ok thanks...i created a helper function to wrap this...thanks again